# 0 tables found using pgsql ODBC in acces

Tags: postgresql, ms-access

so I am trying to use a postgres SQL database in an Access file.

The problem is, when I connect to the database, I got no tables found, while when I test the connection I got a Successful message. But when it should then show a list of the tables found with this ODBC link, nothing.

I took the last ODBC in x64 (got compatibility error in 32) on post gres website.

Data Base version : 9.3.9.

Can someone help me resolve my problem?

If I had an error on the connection I would understand, but as it is successful at thsi step, I don't get why I can't found any tables...

Comment: Obvious question: are the permissions OK? I.e. does the ODBC user account have permissions for any tables?

Comment: please check postgres logs. and btw another obvious question "do you have any table in db, or it is empty just created one?"

Comment: @mlinth if you mean user account in ODBC admin, yeah, it has the required permissions. Otherwise, I don't know where I can manage ODBC account.
VaoTsun yes there is tables, I wouldn't be surprised in the other case.

Comment: could you please  check postgres logs for errors?..